# Forward HTTP request from Azure Public IP port 80 to internet ip with different port

Tags: azure, azure-public-ip

Let's suppose we have the following scenario:

- an on premise server with a public IP (aa.bb.cc.dd) and an application listening on a specific port (8081). port 80 is already used by another app.
- an external application that send HTTP requests to an IP address. I cannot specify the port in the settings.

I would like something that forward xy.xy.xy.xy:80 to aa.bb.cc.dd:8081.

Is it possible to do it with azure? I can create a PublicIP address, but how to forward http request to azure-external ip address with different port? is there something else I can use?

Comment: May be with a vm installed with squid proxy whitelisting `aa.bb.cc.dd:8081` ?

Comment: @harshavmb yes, this is feasible. I would like to know if another option is available (without a vm with extra software)